# Auto scroll in the browser when dragging

Tags: drag-and-drop, zk, autoscroll

I use ZK 6.5 and I have a huge grid (more or less like a planning)

I need to drag-and-drop labels in the cells of the grid.

If my grid has a lot of rows and a label has to be moved from the first line to the last one, I would be great to have a "autoscroll of the page in the browser” when I drop it...

I had read a lot of tuto/docs but I found nothing.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to [this](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/72902/how-to-auto-scroll-a-listbox-when-dragging-a-listtiem/) question. The only way is to customize your drag event